# Is light's momentum $0$?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, momentum, speed-of-light, mass-energy

From Paul Dirac's extended mass-energy equivalence equation, we know that,

E<sup>2</sup> = (mc<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> + (pc)<sup>2</sup>

We also know that E = mc<sup>2</sup>

So, if we write `mc` instead of `E` in the equation and then subtract `mc`<sup>2</sup> from the both side, we get 0 in one side and `(pc)`<sup>2</sup> on the other.

Like so:

E<sup>2</sup> = (mc<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> + (pc)<sup>2</sup>

=> (mc<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = (mc<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> + (pc)<sup>2</sup>

=> (mc<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> - (mc<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = (mc<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> + (pc)<sup>2</sup> - (mc<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>

=> 0 = (pc)<sup>2</sup>

Since, `p` is the momentum, can't we state that light has 0 momentum? Am I missing something? Did I make any mistake in the equation?

Comment: No, you have only concluded that when $E=m_{0}c^2$, p must be zero. $E≠ m_{0}c^2$ in general.

Comment: You're just mixing two definitions of mass, relativistic mass versus rest mass. Which one you call "mass" depends on what kind of physics you do.

Comment: This equation holds for mass and massless  particles where as E=mc^2 does not. This equation IS E=mc^2, when P = $\gamma m_0 v$. in E=mc^2 the m is not rest mass  but instead $\gamma m_{0}$

Comment: Note that nowhere did you use any of the properties of light, so from your (incorrect) work, you would actually conclude that everything has 0 momentum.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with the [energy momentum relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation)
$$
E^2 = \left(m_{0} c^2\right)^2 + \left(pc\right)^2
$$
where $m_{0}$ is the rest/invariant mass, and apply it in the rest frame (where $p = 0$), you get
$$
E = m_{0}c^2
$$
You've turned the argument around, and asked "what are the conditions where $E = m_{0}c^2$?" You found that $p = 0$.

For a photon, $m_{0} = 0$, so the first equation becomes
$$
E = pc \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ p = \frac{E}{c}
$$
[With](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_energy#:%7E:text=Photon%20energy%20is%20the%20energy,frequency%2C%20the%20higher%20its%20energy.) $E = hf = hc/\lambda$, this means the momentum of a photon is
$$
p = \frac{hf}{c} = \frac{h}{\lambda}
$$

Comment: You're using the revisionist definition of mass as "rest mass", but E=mc^2 refers to the older convention where mass is "relativistic mass".

Comment: @JohnDoty I added some clarifications that $m$ is the rest/invariant mass.

Comment: You should also note that the classic, famous formula works fine when m is relativistic mass.

Answer (score 0):

Your original equation is only correct when you mean m to be rest mass, which is actually denoted $m_{0}$. m is actually $\gamma m_{0}$ and is called relativistic mass.

You are finding conditions on the equation that make $E=m_{0}c^2$. Which ultimately give $P = 0$. Have you noticed that your reasoning has nothing to do with light?
You're just proving that $P=0$ when your condition is met.

Your mistake lies in the fact that you believe $E=m_{0}c^2$ holds in general. It does not. Only when momentum is zero does this hold.

The standard equation:

$$E=mc^2 = \gamma m_{0}c^2$$

Which I believe you were trying to assert  is true always, is also not true in general. (instead of the equation with $m_{0}$)

Substituting this correctly, as you were trying to do, yields that when $E=\gamma m_{0} c^2$

$$P = \gamma m_{0} v$$

Which is the equation for momentum of a massive body.

This does not apply for light,  since atleast in the context of classical electrodynamics, the field momentum is denoted by
$$P = \mu_{0} \epsilon_{0} \vec{S}$$

As pointed above, when $m_{0} = 0$, $E=pc$, which is the equation for the energy of light. ( which can also be independantly derived  from maxwells equations)

Comment: For light,  is infinite and 0  is zero, so the equation for a massive body does not apply. Still, you should note that Einstein's "radiation in a box" argument shows that it is sensible to attribute mass to light.

Comment: Comparing the momentum equation to field momentum is an equally valid way of showing  this regardless. But I would  argue your way is actually better since $\gamma$ is actually undefined not infinity.

Comment: And for  the box thought experiment, I believe it more sensible to associate an inertia to the system, rather than associate a mass to the light itself.

Comment: The  math depends on how you choose to compactify the complex plane. *Mathematica* tells me that  is *ComplexInfinity* for β→1. But that's just math. Physically it seems more straightforward to attribute the mass transfer to the light itself, even though you may attribute it differently in the abstract math. In the end, it makes no difference, except that E=mc^2 is one of the most illuminating physics ideas of all time. Hiding this behind abstraction is not progress.

Comment: Remember we aren't dealing with limits, B is 1, not the limit as B goes to 1.

Comment: I was using *Mathematica* notation, where β→1 means "substitute 1 for β" unless it's in an explicit "Limit" context. *Mathematica* thinks the limit is "Indeterminate". But this is all dependent on arbitrary mathematical choices. For physics, what happens in experiments is what matters.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is simple to think in terms of classical light as the ensemble of photons, quantum mechanical particles obeying the Lorentz transformations.

This means that a photon, which has zero mass, will  have a [four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html)

[image: four vect]

Zero mass particles do have  a momentum, setting $m_0$ to zero and thus getting the momentum of the photon $pc=E$ .

The classical light is built up by a large number of photons whose momenta will add up to the momentum of a beam of light.

[This answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/592251/single-photon-beam-in-ydse/592254#592254) gives an intuition of the complex way single photons build up classical light.
.